# How to open MODIS NetCDF file in R?

Tags: r, netcdf

I am trying to open a MODIS Aqua NetCDF file (https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI/2010/001/) in R. I have tried many packages, but none seems to be able to deal with the file format.

```r
library(ncdf4)
```

This is not working.

```r
nc_open("~/Desktop/A20100012010008.L3b_8D_CHL.nc")
#> Error in ncvar_type_to_string(rv$precint): Error, unrecognized type code of variable supplied: -1
```

However, it works with all other NetCDF files. For instance, I can open CCI merged files.

```r
head(nc_open("~/Desktop/ESACCI-OC-L3S-CHLOR_A-MERGED-1M_MONTHLY_4km_GEO_PML_OCx-201701-fv5.0.nc"))
#> $filename
#> [1] "~/Desktop/ESACCI-OC-L3S-CHLOR_A-MERGED-1M_MONTHLY_4km_GEO_PML_OCx-201701-fv5.0.nc"
#> 
#> $writable
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $id
#> [1] 131072
#> 
#> $safemode
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $format
#> [1] "NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4_CLASSIC"
#> 
#> $is_GMT
#> [1] FALSE
```

Any ideas on why this is not working?

<sup>Created on 2021-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Check the file size and make sure you got the complete file? `file.size(file.choose())`

Comment: It is approximately 180 Mb. It does the same on all files I have tried.

Comment: This person has same error message, https://github.com/hypertidy/ncmeta/issues/3 maybe the `ncmeta` package can find the problem?

Comment: groups and compound types, ncdf4 and RNetCDF don't support compound type - need rhdf5, e.g. https://github.com/sosoc/croc/blob/master/R/read_L3_file_hdf5.R

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at one of those ["Binned" files](https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODIS-Aqua/Binned/8-Day/CHL/) using `ncdump`, it had group attributes, which means it uses the [NetCDF enhanced data model](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf_data_model.html).
As such, it isn't supported by most netCDF software. `ncdump` should allow you to do a bulk export to text. Another possibility is to read the file using HDF5 library. Otherwise, I suggest you obtain the data in some other way. Perhaps the NetCDF files which work may have the same data, just packaged differently?
Here is part of the `ncdump` output

```
group: level-3_binned_data {
  types:
    compound binListType {
      uint bin_num ;
      short nobs ;
      short nscenes ;
      float weights ;
      float time_rec ;
    }; // binListType
    compound binDataType {
      float sum ;
      float sum_squared ;
    }; // binDataType
    compound binIndexType {
      uint start_num ;
      uint begin ;
      uint extent ;
      uint max ;
    }; // binIndexType
  dimensions:
        binListDim = UNLIMITED ; // (5643478 currently)
        binDataDim = UNLIMITED ; // (5643478 currently)
        binIndexDim = UNLIMITED ; // (4320 currently)
  variables:
        binListType BinList(binListDim) ;
        binDataType chlor_a(binDataDim) ;
        binDataType chl_ocx(binDataDim) ;
        binIndexType BinIndex(binIndexDim) ;
  data:
  } // group level-3_binned_data
```