# cant read the netcdf file

Tags: r, netcdf

I am trying to load netcdf file into R:

```
f <- "A20020012002365.L3b_YR_CHL.nc"
u <- "https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/"
curl::curl_download(file.path(u, f), f)
r <- brick("A20020012002365.L3b_YR_CHL.nc")
```

Error message I get:
`Error in R_nc4_open: NetCDF: Unknown file format`

Also tried:

```
tidync::tidync("A20020012002365.L3b_YR_CHL.nc")
nc <-  RNetCDF::open.nc("A20020012002365.L3b_YR_CHL.nc")
RNetCDF::print.nc(nc)
file <- RNetCDF::open.nc("A20020012002365.L3b_YR_CHL.nc")
ncdf4::nc_open("A20020012002365.L3b_YR_CHL.nc", verbose=TRUE, readunlim = FALSE, suppress_dimvals = TRUE)
```

none of those worked

Comment: Upon closer inspection: if you run the commands above, the file that gets downloaded is an HTML page that requests your login / authentication (though presenting with a .nc file extension). At least for me. You'd best verify you have the correct file by downloading it manually through the NASA website.

Comment: I have a .NC file downloaded with this code

Comment: I am using R cause I do not have another program to check, I tried to run the following:
file  <-  RNetCDF::open.nc("A20020012002365.L3b_YR_CHL.nc")
RNetCDF::print.nc(file)
class(file)
gives me class NetCDF

Comment: Alright, for me the command `file <- RNetCDF::open.nc("A20020012002365.L3b_YR_CHL.nc")` already gives an error: `NetCDF: Unknown file format`. So you have another problem. I don't have a login to access these files so can't help you further unfortunately.

Comment: i asked a friend to check with matlab, and file opens perfectly

Comment: These are not regular gridded data. You should be able to open the file with an hdf5 library if you know something about the underlying data structure. Otherwise, see discussion on the earthdata forum https://forum.earthdata.nasa.gov/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1903

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66296373/how-to-open-modis-netcdf-file-in-r